# How did Nevada Governor Joe Lombardo explain why he vetoed a bill that would ban people from acting as fake electors?

Tags: presidential-election, electoral-college, us-state-laws, state-legislatures, nevada

Politico's Nov 15, 2023 [Nevada attorney general is investigating false electors who aided Trump in 2020](https://www.politico.com/news/2023/11/15/nevada-false-electors-trump-investigation-00127369) includes the following, quoting [Nevada Attorney General Aaron Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_D._Ford):

> ...an American lawyer and politician serving as the 34th Attorney General of Nevada, since 2019. A member of the Democratic Party, (Ford) previously served as a Nevada State Senator for the 11th district from 2013 to 2018, which encompasses parts of the Las Vegas Valley including portions of the communities of Spring Valley and Enterprise.
>
> “As you all know, I have been silent on Nevada’s fake electors, except to say that the matter was on our radar,” he said in [testimony to the state’s legislature](https://thenevadaindependent.com/article/ag-says-nevada-will-not-bring-charges-against-gop-fake-electors-urges-law-change). “With it on our radar, we ascertained that current state statutes did not directly address the conduct in question — to the dismay of some, and I’m sure, to the delight of others.”
>
> In that hearing, he testified in favor of a proposal to ban people from acting as fake electors, [the Nevada Independent reported](https://thenevadaindependent.com/article/ag-says-nevada-will-not-bring-charges-against-gop-fake-electors-urges-law-change). **The bill passed through the state’s Democratic-controlled legislature [and was vetoed](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/App/NELIS/REL/82nd2023/Bill/9810/Overview) in June by its Republican governor, Joe Lombardo.**
>
> Then, in September, Ford appeared to change his tune. “I’ve never said that we’re not going to prosecute,” he told 8 News Now. “It is not that I’ve said that I can do nothing. What I have said, and I’ve been precise with my wording on purpose, is we don’t have statutes in this state that directly address the issue.”

**Question:** How did [Nevada Governor Joe Lombardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Lombardo) explain why he vetoed a bill that would ban people from acting as fake electors? Did he make an argument *for* fake electors? Cite constitutional concerns? Something else?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can read the letter of objections Lombardo attached to the bill when he returned it to the Nevada Senate [here](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/23833016-sb133-veto-message). His argument against the bill is essentially that it introduces "disproportionately harsh penalties" for offenders, rather than doing anything to improve the security of elections.

> I believe ensuring the sanctity and security of our elections is
> paramount to maintaining public confidence in both our electoral
> processes and in elected officials. There should be strict punishments
> for those seeking to undermine that confidence, including those
> engaged in schemes to present slates of false electors.
>
> That said, it is difficult to fathom how the penalty for being engaged
> in such a scheme should be harsher — in terms of time-served and by
> requiring a permanent relinquishment of certain unrelated employment
> rights — than the penalty for high-level fentanyl traffickers, certain
> domestic violence perpetrators, and even some of the most extreme and
> violent actors on January 6.
>
> Because SB 133 does nothing to ensure the security of our elections
> and merely provides disproportionately harsh penalties for an,
> admittedly, terrible crime, I cannot support it.

Comment: To provide context: 1) "*SB 133 does nothing to ensure the security of our elections*", the Gov proposed his own election security bill [SB 405](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/App/NELIS/REL/82nd2023/Bill/10413/Text) which contained such greatest voter suppression hits as Voter ID requirements and restricting vote-by-mail, 2) "*merely provides disproportionately harsh penalties*" SB 133 would make it a category B felony, same as treason (which, one can argue, fake presidential electors are at that scale of crime) and some security exchange crimes.